# vCard Custom fields different behavior on 16.08 and 18.01

Tags: ejabberd, vcf-vcard

i am using ejabberd 16.08 on production and 18.01 on dev, we use Smack XMPP to get and set vCards, the below code works correctly on 16.08.

```
VCard vCard = new VCard()
vCard.setFirstName("MyName")
vCard.setField("myCustomField", "0002@0000@0000")
```

With this code i can set and get myCustomField, but on version 18.01 it stopped working, the same code but when i get the vCard it has only the commons properties.
I looked in Release Notes and commits for the latest version but i cant figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Right, since ejabberd 16.12, mod_vcard and most of ejabberd uses a different, more strict XML library. See the [commit](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/9a8e197d7e03298fce9cec030ae961ca7814419e) and [release notes](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-16-12/).

So, only the fields described in [the XEP](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html) and accepted by the library are finally stored.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
So there are any alternatives? Our use case is that we need custom information from xmpp users.